# Get values depending on key in nested list of object

Tags: javascript

Let's start with a quick example to better understand my issue, I have this object :

```
{
    "list_of_objects" : [
        {
            "name" : "0",
            "interesting_key" : "some_value",
        },
        {
            "name" : "1",
            "interesting_key" : "some_other_value",
            "list_of_objects" : [
                {
                    "name" : "10",
                    "interesting_key" : "something"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "11"
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            "name" : "2",
            "interesting_key" : "again_some_other_value",
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get all the values corresponding to `interesting_key`, **is there a way to do it without looping over each list of objects**? Something that would result like this :

```
["some_value", "some_other_value", "something", "again_some_other_value"]
```

I want to do this so I can compare only object containing `interesting_key`.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Comment: I think you basically asked a variant of the P versus NP problem rn...

Comment: Nope is not possible

Comment: One way (recursion): https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/btL1vh6f/ (although not sure if that fits your constraint of not looping)

Comment: @DaveSmith  `is there a way to do it without looping over each list of objects` The answer is `No`. You might use functions of javascript, but that internally loops under the hood anyway. Surely, you can't not check the object, yet produce correct results.

Comment: @vivek_23 Right, thanks, fixed :)

Answer (score 2):

You could recursively search for the key like this:

```js
const list_of_objects=[{"name":"0","interesting_key":"some_value",},{"name":"1","interesting_key":"some_other_value","list_of_objects":[{"name":"10","interesting_key":"something"},{"name":"11"},]},{"name":"2","interesting_key":"again_some_other_value",}]

function findNestedValues(array, key) {
  return array.reduce((r, obj) => {
    if(key in obj) 
      r.push(obj[key])
    
    if(obj.list_of_objects)
      r.push(...findNestedValues(obj.list_of_objects, key))
    
    return r
  }, [])
}

console.log(findNestedValues(list_of_objects, "interesting_key"))
```

Comment: Interesting recursive approach. As a side note, you may parametrize `list_of_objects` as well, or you may just want to check each key to check whether it's an array and eventually lookup on that key too.

Comment: @briosheje thanks for the suggestion, I realize that I shouldn't have put the same key for the second `list_of_objects` in my example as this can be something else indeed

Comment: @DaveSmith This can easily be solved in adiga's snippet, the approach is actually fine, to me, it's just matter of refining it a bit :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a string version

```js
const re = /"interesting_key":"(.*?)"/g

const str=JSON.stringify({"list_of_objects":[{"name":"0","interesting_key":"some_value",},{"name":"1","interesting_key":"some_other_value","list_of_objects":[{"name":"10","interesting_key":"something"},{"name":"11"},]},{"name":"2","interesting_key":"again_some_other_value",}]});
let result = [];

while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
  result.push(match[1])
}
console.log(result)
```

Shorter

```js
const re = /"interesting_key":"(.*?)"/g

const str=JSON.stringify({"list_of_objects":[{"name":"0","interesting_key":"some_value",},{"name":"1","interesting_key":"some_other_value","list_of_objects":[{"name":"10","interesting_key":"something"},{"name":"11"},]},{"name":"2","interesting_key":"again_some_other_value",}]});

let result = []
str.replace(re,(a,b) => result.push(b) )
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a recursive function which loop through your data like the following code:

```js
var list = [
  {
      "name" : "0",
      "interesting_key" : "some_value",
  },
  {
      "name" : "1",
      "interesting_key" : "some_other_value",
      "list_of_objects" : [
          {
              "name" : "10",
              "interesting_key" : "something"
          },
          {
              "name" : "11"
          },
      ]
  },
  {
      "name" : "2",
      "interesting_key" : "again_some_other_value",
  }
]
var interestingKey = [];
function getInterestingKey (list) {
  list.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.interesting_key) {
      interestingKey.push(item.interesting_key);
    }
    if (item.list_of_objects) {
      getInterestingKey(item.list_of_objects);
    }
  })
  return interestingKey;
}

console.log(getInterestingKey(list))
```